# Multiple objects in GLUT

Tags: c, glut

I want to multiply an object(cube) to a certain number, in this case let's say 25, and I do have the code for one cube, and it works, but I can't figure out how to make more. I am a new-comer to GLUT.

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void initGL(int width, int height)
{

 glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
 glLoadIdentity();
 gluPerspective(45.0f,(GLfloat)width/(GLfloat)height,2.0f, 100.0f);
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
static void display(void)
{

glLoadIdentity();
glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-10);
    glRotatef(60,1,0,0);
    glRotatef(60,0,1,0);
    glutSolidCube(2);
glPopMatrix();

glFlush();
}

static void idle(void)
{
glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

int width = 640;
int height = 480;

glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
glutInitWindowPosition(10,10);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_SINGLE);

glutCreateWindow("GLUT cube");

glutDisplayFunc(display);
glutIdleFunc(idle);

initGL(width, height);

glutMainLoop();

return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

And if there is a more detailed guide on how to, I'd be more than thankful if you share.

Comment: What do you mean by "multiply"? Do you mean increasing its size, or drawing more than one object?

Comment: more of the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call `glutSolidCube()`, it draws one cube. If you want more than one cube to appear, you'll need to call the function more than once in your implementation of `display()`.

(Make sure you change the model matrix between each call! Otherwise, the cubes will end up in the same place.)

Comment: So I would copy-paste the display content into itself and change coordinates?